# EXPTIME in Oracle database stands for?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I want to know the table name and what it actually stands for - EXPTIME apart from CTIME, LTIME and PTIME

Comment: What is the context?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about `user$` table?

If yes then the column `EXPTIME` stands for EXPiry TIME and represents(with conjunction `ASTATUS` ACCOUNT_STATUS) with  `EXPIRY_DATE` on `dba_users` table, which mean Date of expiration of the account.

`USER$` is  Oracle's internal tables and undocumented.